# How to copy child element n times in XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, using

I am very new to XSLT.  I need to transform and copy child nodes 1000 times and also increment the id node so that they are different each time.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <id>2017</id>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**My XSLT: but it only copies once**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**What I need is:  Please help**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"   href="test.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <id>2017</id>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
   </cd>
    <cd>
        <id>2018</id>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
   </cd>
   <cd>
        <id>2019</id>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
   </cd>

    <!-- 997 more times with ID increment +1 each time  -->

</catalog>
```

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 1.0, you can achieve this by using a recursive template. So the template repeatedly calls itself, incrementing a parameter each time until it reaches the required limit.

Try this XSLT (replace the parameter 5 with 1000, as required)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="total" select="5" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd" name="cd">
    <xsl:param name="count" select="1" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="$count &lt; $total">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="id">
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="number() + $count - 1" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If you want the same logic but for other elements under `cd`, simply amend the template matching `id` to include them in the match. For example..

```
<xsl:template match="id|year">
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="number() + $count - 1" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See this in action at http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLv

Comment: If I added another template after the match="id" say match="year" and do  <xsl:value-of select="number() + $count - 1" />, I get <year>NaN</year>.  Any idea why?

Comment: Does the `<year>` tag actually contain a number, or is it empty?

Comment: The year contains number and not blank.  I even tried to use 'format-number(number() + $count + 1, "0")', but I am getting "NaN" as well.  Actually, in my real XML file, the tag is not called "year", it is called "ReviewID" and has value 1234 which I want to increment by 1 as well.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include the "ReviewID" field you are having an issue with. Or, if your actual XML is quite different to what is shown in this current question, it might be better for you to ask a whole new question. Thanks!

Comment: Tim, to keep it simple, let's say I would like to have the year tag to increment as well, or even copy the same incremented value from "id" to "year".  Thanks Tim.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't work for you, but I have made an edit to my answer to show something that does work for me. See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLv

Comment: I see that it works for you.  Thank you Tim for your time.